How to connect Quarkus app to a database?
So I'm trying to connect a Quarkus app to my local database. I created a simple database using SSMS with 1 simple table and for now I'm not trying to do anything specific with this app, I'm just trying to fetch the data and display it, I just want to make the connection work properly.
I installed JDBC and agroal extensions and configured the connection using application.properties and I don't know why it doesn't work.
My application.properties file looks like this:
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mssql
quarkus.datasource.username=Mmm\\filip
quarkus.datasource.password=
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test

(It's just a local database and I don't use any password to log in).
And that's how my endpoint looks like:
package org.acme;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import io.agroal.pool.DataSource;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    public GreetingResource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> hello() {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT nazwa FROM dbo.Table_2";
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                results.add(rs.getString("nazwa"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
}

And currently after running the app and going to "http://localhost:8080/hello" I get this:

io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceException

The stacktrace below has been reversed to show the root cause first. See the original stacktrace
jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:519)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:308)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:488)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Resulted in: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1508)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:320)
    ... 12 more
Resulted in: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1508)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:320)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:488)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Resulted in: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:519)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:308)
    ... 12 more

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:330)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.reloadExistingApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:264)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.reloadExistingApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartApp(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:190)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartCallback(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:173)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:542)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:442)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$6.call(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:161)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$6.call(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:148)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$0(ContextImpl.java:178)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$internalExecuteBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1495)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:11)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:11)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Resulted in: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1508)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:320)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:488)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Resulted in: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.pool.DataSource and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: parameter 'dataSource' of org.acme.GreetingResource constructor
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.GreetingResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.GreetingResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:519)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:308)
    ... 12 more

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:334)
    ... 19 more
Resulted in: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceException


Aren't Quarkus deployments executed in k8s pods? Unless there's a Windows authenticated SQL Server instance installed in the pod along with it it's unlikely to be able to connect to localhost:1433.
